# Is there a way to create a form with several selects, and point to each member id depending on a database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

My problem is that the selects use the same name and the values ​​are not assigned to each member, is there any way to get each select to be assigned to a specific member id?

I attach the code for better understanding.

Keep in mind that there are several members and the table automatically expands, adding more forms.

```html
<?php
include_once 'conexion.php';

$sql = mysqli_query ($conexion, "SELECT * FROM miembros ORDER BY IdMiembro");


date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Madrid');

$i=0;
?>

<form action="" method="post">
<center><table width="40%" border="1">
<tr>
    <td width="68%"><center>Nombre</center></td>
    <td width="18%"><center>Fecha</center></td>
    <td width="14%"><center>Presente</center></td>
</tr>
<?php while($mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $mostrar['IdMiembro'];?></td>
    <td><input type="date"  value='<?php echo date('Y-m-d');?>' name="fecha" ></td>
    <td><select name="eleccion">
        <option value="0">Presente</option>
        <option value="1">Llega tarde</option>
        <option value="2">Ausente</option>
    </select></td>
    </tr>
<?php 
    $i++;
}?>
</table>

<br /><br />

<input type="submit" value="Insertar Asistencia" name="enviar">
</center>
</form>

<?php

    if(isset($_POST['enviar'])) {
        for ($b=1; $b<=$i; $b++) {
            
        }
        
    }

?>
```

Comment: You only have one form, containing multiple selects. Are you expecting to be able to submit data for each member separately, or update them all at once with a single submit? That decision affects how you design the form and the structure of the selects

Comment: Update them all at once.

Comment: Ok so use `<select name="eleccion[]">` and also have a hidden field e.g. `<input name="memberID[]" ...` which has the ID in it. Then in the submitted data `$_POST["eleccion"]` will be an array containing all the values from the dropdowns and `$_POST["memberID"]` will be an array of all the member IDs. That way you can match them up, because (for example) the value in `$_POST["elecction"][0]` will belong to the member ID held in `$_POST["memberID"][0]`, and so on. So in your PHP you can easily loop through them to collect and store all the data.

Comment: Use the "array syntax" for form field names, and put the member ID into the brackets, like `name="eleccion[123]"` Then `$_POST['eleccion']` will be an array that uses the member ID as key, and you can easily loop over it using the extended foreach syntax.

Comment: Or you can do it as CBroe says, which is a variation on the same idea, but arguably a bit neater.

Comment: Thank you so much to both! I'm going to implement it in my code